# How to get modified object after dragging?

Tags: angularjs

I use drag and drop [library](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists)

I use directive for dragging element:

```
dnd-moved="movedSongCallback(list, $index)"
```

And function:

```
$scope.movedSongCallback = function (data, index){
            data.people.splice(index, 1);
});
```

So, inside functon I get old `data` instead modified.

How to get modified object after dragging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dragend event is furnished in the local `event` variable:

```
dnd-moved="movedSongCallback(list, $index, event)"
```

JS

```
$scope.movedSongCallback = function (data, index, event){
    data.people.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    console.log(event.relatedTarget);
});
```